MySQL WorkbenchにあるOptions Fileが表示されない
MacOSを使用しています。my.cnfファイルを探してみようとこのコマンドを打った結果、いくつかの同名ファイルが見つかりました。
mysql --help | grep -A 1 "Default options"
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

プラグインの有効化など色々と設定したいのですがどのmy.cnfファイルに書き加えれば良いのでしょうか？また、Options Fileに表示させるには何をしたら良いのでしょうか？MySQLは使い始めたばかりでわからないことが多いのでできるだけ噛み砕いて説明していただけると大変助かります。

